# preg_match_all to find a string that may contain some html tags?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

My blog articles have a function where a visitor can select part of it and leave a feedback. The feedback's subject is the selection: it can be a few words, or a phrase with some html tags within it (not necessarily around it.)

My function, up until now was the below:

```
function enco_str_replace_nth( $search, $replace, $subject, $nth = 0 ) {

    $found = preg_match_all( '/' . preg_quote( $search ) . '/', $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );

    if (false !== $found && $found > $nth) {
        return substr_replace( $subject, $replace, $matches[0][$nth][1], strlen( $search ) );
    }

    return $subject;
}
```

It does work when there is no HTML tag(s).

```
a completely organic product
```

But shows a **Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier** and doesn't work when there is HTML in it.

```
MSM is a  <strong>natural nutrient</strong>
```

or

```
because <em>it matters</em> to all of us
```

Any idea of what I should change in this preg_match_all?

Comment: Just use other delimiters (e.g. `~`), problem is that the `/` is not escaped.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comment:

```
function enco_str_replace_nth( $search, $replace, $subject, $nth = 0 ) {
    $found = preg_match_all( '~' . preg_quote( $search ) . '~', $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );

    if (false !== $found && $found > $nth) {
        return substr_replace( $subject, $replace, $matches[0][$nth][1], strlen( $search ) );
    }

    return $subject;
}
```

Comment: It does not show the warning anymore, but it does not match either with this edit. I also tried with # .. # as delimiters.

Comment: @Lazhar: Can you provide some `$search` and `$subject` strings then?